# Jquery Google Autocomplete not working - No error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I had this working a while back and i've come back to it today and I cant seem to get it working and I'm pretty sure I haven't changed anything.

Live preview: http://cssdeck.com/labs/wlt4zing

Here is the html:

```
 <div class='form-row'>
<div class='col-6 form-group'>
<label class='control-label'>Location</label>
<input class='form-control' id='autocomplete'
placeholder='Location' size='4' type='text'>
<input class="input hidden" disabled="true" id="route">
<input class="input hidden" disabled="true" id=
"locality"> <input class="input hidden" disabled="true"
id="administrative_area_level_1"> <input class=
"input hidden" disabled="true" id=
"administrative_area_level_2"> <input class=
"input hidden" disabled="true" id="postal_code">
<input class="input hidden" disabled="true" id=
"country">
</div>
   <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
```

JS

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'long_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
};
function clear(){
    console.log("clr");
    $("input.hidden").val("");
}
function initialize() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
        types: ['geocode']
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        fillInAddress();
    });
}

function fillInAddress() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();   

    for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = '';
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#autocomplete" ).on('keyup',function() { 
        $("input.hidden").val('');
    });
});
```

I don't get any errors so I'm not sure what has gone wrong. It should fetch autocomplete suggestions and fill in the fields but it doesn't do anything. Can anyone help me please understand where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call `initialize()`. You should call it on page load.